# SQL issue; count + display

Tags: sql, oracle

After searching for more than 2 hours on the internet I have not found a specific answer to my questions :

1) How to display only 3 columns of a specific table ?
2) How to count (the sum) of a column in a table.

Comment: I'm curious. What exactly were your search terms?

Comment: Well, my initial problem was this : 
Display the StaffNo, fName and BranchNo for each staff (in Staff table); the count of properties (in PropertyforRent table) managed by that Staff; and the list of PropertyNo, Type, Street, and city for each property that the Staff manage.

Comment: Perhaps this would be helpful: http://plsql-tutorial.com/

Comment: No PL/SQL is required for those tasks. Plain SQL is more than enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to display all the columns of the table you should specify the names of the columns you want to display:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM table;
```

If you want to add all the values of a column:

```
SELECT SUM(column1)
FROM table;
```

If you wanted to display the summatory along with other columns, then you should group by those columns:

```
SELECT column1, column2, SUM(column3)
FROM table
GROUP BY column1, column2;
```

If you want to count the number of rows --it works just like the SUM function--:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 2):

1) How to display only 3 columns of a specific table ?

```
select t.column_1,
       t.column_2,
       t.column_3
  from some_table t;
```

2) How to count (the sum) of a column in a table.

```
 select sum(t.amount)
     from salary t
    where t.employee_id = 5;
```

3) How to count records in table

```
 select count(*)
   from employee;
```

Comment: In #1 you don't show 3 columns, but 3 (random) rows.